# Unable to select a 3 point button in Sharepoint using Selenium WebDriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium, button, sharepoint

I am trying to automate a SharePoint site, using Selenium Java. I want my web driver to go to one file, move it and save it into the target folder.
There is a 3 dot menu, if we click, then it displays options like move, delete, download  etc I tried the Xpath but it is not recognizing as there are multiple 3 point buttons for different files in the same webpage with no unique id.
To recognize the button, I used complete XPath but did not work.
Also, can I use the Actions class once I am able to select the button?
Any recommendations?

Copied below is the source code for the button I want to select.

Xpath for button1 (Target folder)
/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/section/article/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/button[2]

Xpath for button2 (source file)
/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/section/article/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/button[2]

Comment: please share screenshot and code snipet. that would be more helpful

Comment: Use implicit wait and dynamic xpaths instead of absolute. In case of persistence, update your question with your code and url or html source code.

Comment: @JayanthBala Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider suggesting OP to update the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Yes , it worked after using implicit wait and dynamic Xpath.

Comment: //input[@id='rc_select_0'])[1]", this Xpath with index also worked for me. If I don't give the index the Webdriver wasn't selecting any element. I also used Thread. sleep(5000) in order to open up the tree path and select the file.